# Retrieving the 3D Position of a Rectangle Using a Single 2D Image

Tags: geometry, 3d, projective-geometry, projection

The setup is as following:

- a rectangular object whose width and height are known is placed somewhere in 3D space
- an image is taken of the object producing a 2D projection of the rectangle onto an imaging plane

**Given the coordinates of the four vertices of the rectangular object in the 2D image is it possible to determine the coordinates of the rectangular object in 3D space relative to the camera position?**

I've found a paper claiming to do exactly that ([semanticscholar](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Finding-3-D-Positions-from-2-D-Images-Feasibility-Prematunga/1d4c43e5de088852c763dbc5584216692d786133), [pdf](https://www.thinkmind.org/articles/icons_2012_11_10_90008.pdf)). However, the authors' claim of retrieving a rectangular object in 3D space is not correct, because the only constraint they take into account is that $P_0P_1 = P_2P_3$ (i.e. that the opposite sides are of equal length) ensure that the object is a parallelogram but not necessarily a rectangle.

Since the system of equations they got is completely determined, is there a way to ensure that the resulting coordinates are indeed of a *rectangular* object?

If not, how would one begin to add error terms to the original coordinates without getting completely entangled in the expressions? Otherwise, is there another approach to take for the same problem?

The paper mentioned:
Prematunga, H.G.L. and Dharmaratne, A.T. (2012). Finding 3D Positions from 2D Images Feasibility Analysis. In In Proc. of The Seventh International Conference on Systems (ICONS 2012).

**[EDIT]** I haven't properly emphasized that the output must necessarily be a rectangle, if that is not the case, the 2D points are misplaced. In that case, it would be useful to find a meaningful way to transform the coordinates of the 3D parallelogram into a
rectangle with the least degree of error.

Comment: But the object is known to be a rectangle.

Comment: I don't understand: if you don't get a rectangle, then the 3d object is not a rectangle.

Comment: It is, however, the 2D measurements may have some degree of error, I didn't explain that properly in the question. What I missed was that the presented solution is in fact unique, i.e. that for some sets of points the only solution that is a parallelogram isn't a rectangle as well. Do you think there is an elegant way of approximating the output with a rectangle regardless?

Comment: It is easy to get a rectangle if you can tweak a little the value of $l$, the distance from the plane of the image to the centre of the camera. In that case an expression for the right value of $l$ can be found.

Answer (score 1):

I've read the problem formulation in the paper, and from what I understand, you basically have four image points of the rectangle vertices, let's call them $q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4 $ ordered in (anti-) clockwise direction.  From the camera model, the actual positions of the vertices is given by

$ p_1 = - t_1 q_1 , p_2 = -t_2 q_2 , p_3 = -t_3 q_3, p_4 = -t_4 q_4 $

where $t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4 \gt 0 $

The main equation here is that

$ p_1 p_2 = p_4 p_3 $

(remember the order of the points)

Hence,

$ -t_2 q_2 + t_1 q_1 = -t_3 q_3 + t_4 q_4 $

If we define the $3 \times 4$ matrix $Q$ as follows

$ Q = \begin{bmatrix} q_1 && - q_2 && q_3 && -q_4 \end{bmatrix} $

and the vector $T = \begin{bmatrix} t_1 \\ t_2 \\ t_3 \\ t_4 \end{bmatrix} $

Then

$Q T = 0 $

This is a linear system of $3$ equations in $4$ unknowns, and can be solved to yield

$T = \lambda V $

where $V$ is a constant vector resulting from solving the above linear system, and $\lambda$ is an arbitrary real scalar.  From the nature of the problem we want to take the entries of $V$ to be all positive and $\lambda \gt 0$ as well.

Finally, we have

$ |p_1 p_2 |^2 = a^2 $

where $a$ is the known length of the rectangle.  Therefore,

$  \| -t_2 q_2 + t_1 q_1 \|^2 = a^2 $

and this simplifies to,

$ \| - \lambda V_2 q_2 + \lambda V_1 q_1 \|^2 = a^2$

which simplifies further to,

$ \lambda^2 \| - V_2 q_2 + V_1 q_1 \|^2 = a^2 $

which directly results in the positive value of $\lambda$.  Once $\lambda$ is known, all the $t$'s are known and thus all the vertices coordinates become known.

At the final stage, after having computed all the coordinates we can check that

$ p_1 p_2 \perp p_2 p_3 $

Note that this condition is equivalent to

$ \lambda^2 ( V_2 q_2 - V1 q_1 ) \cdot ( V_3 q_3 - V2 q_2 ) = 0 $

Therefore, and since $\lambda \ne 0$, if the imaged quadrilateral is indeed a rectangle we must have

$ ( V_2 q_2 - V_1 q_1 ) \cdot ( V_3 q_3 - V_2 q_2 ) = 0 $

If this condition is satisfied then our quadrilateral is indeed a rectangle, otherwise, it is a parallelogram.

One could also check that

$ \| p_2 p_3 \| = b $

where $b$ is the other dimension of the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds right, however, what I know is that the object is in fact a rectangle so I should get a rectangle as an output, anything other than that indicates errors in the input data. 
That's what I was clumsily mentioning in the question. The data points (2D coordinates) aren't 100% correct. If they were I would always get a rectangle using this method. 
What I was asking is was whether there is a way to force the output into a rectangular shape that most aligns with the 2D data.

Comment: @sena Ideally, you should choose your input data so that the result is a rectangle. It should be possible to do so, I think, by forcing the data to give some cross-ratio which we know to be the right one for a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get a rectangle is that of changing the value of $l$, the distance from the plane of the image to the centre of the camera. Using the notations described in [the cited paper](https://www.thinkmind.org/articles/icons_2012_11_10_90008.pdf), after we get $t_2=at_0$, $t_3=bt_0$ and $t_1=t_0+t_3-t_2$ (from the equation $P_1-P_0=P_3-P_2$), we can enforce two sides to be perpendicular setting their scalar product to zero, for instance with the equation $(P_2-P_0)\cdot(P_2-P_3)=0$. This can easily be solved for $l$:
$$
l=\sqrt{(x_0-ax_2)(bx_3-ax_2)+(y_0-ay_2)(by_3-ay_2)\strut
\over(a-1)(b-a)\strut}.
$$
If you need to leave $l$ at a fixed value, you could then think of displacing each point $I_k$ along the line joining it to the origin, by a ratio $s$. Substituting $I_k\to sI_k$ into the above equation leads to the following solution for $s$:
$$
s=l\sqrt{
(a-1)(b-a)\strut\over
(x_0-ax_2)(bx_3-ax_2)+(y_0-ay_2)(by_3-ay_2)\strut}.
$$